# Concern about the Lucas primality test

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primality-test

The [Lucas primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test) states that a number N is prime iff there exists a base $B, 1 < B < n$, such that:

[a] $\ B^{N-1} \equiv 1 \pmod N$

...and...

[b] $B^{(N-1)/F} \not\equiv 1 \pmod N$ for all prime factors $F$ of $N-1$.

Now we could select B at random but then the test wouldn't be deterministic. In order to force it to be so we would have to try every possible base until either [a] or [b] fails. So what's the lower bound? Well for most numbers I assume it's fairly reasonable but for one class of numbers at least it's in the neighborhood of $\ N^{1/3}$ : the Carmichael numbers. In fact, the only bases that give a definitive answer for a Carmichael are those that contain at least one of its factors. In other words, trial division would beat a Lucas primality test on these numbers!

So my concern here is whether or not this fact has been taken into account (or is at least a documented caveat) in the definition of [Pratt certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate) and such?

*** EDIT ***

I guess the takeaway here is that, while having little to no value as a strictly deterministic test, the Lucas primality test is nonetheless an excellent probabilistic method. That is the chance that any given number base yields a correct answer is basically 50% and therefore even with respect to Carmichaels, where the number of bases NOT coprime to its prime factors are indisputably plentiful, the probability of finding a suitable base at random is actually quite high. (Depending on the number of trials of course.)

Special thanks to Peter for the helpful comments. Cheers everyone!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In fact , this test is useless , if we happen to have a Carmichael number with large smallest prime factor and test the bases in increasing order. Moreover, this test requires the factorization of N-1, so it is of limited value anyway. But the method is usually powerful, if  we want to prove a probable prime to be prime and we know the factorization of N-1. And usually, we will find a base $B$ doing the job soon.

Comment: This seems to be a much too restrictive statement of the test. We only care about factors of $2$ in $N-1$. Anyway, making the test deterministic is only feasible in decent time if we assume the Riemann hypothesis (as far as I recall).

Comment: Ahh, it seems I misremembered which primality test was which. I was thinking of the Miller-Rabin test instead.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The Miller-Rabin-test is efficient and deterministic , if the generalized riemann hypothesis is true (see here  http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/MillersTest.html  ). But Miller-Rabin uses the strong fermat-pseudoprime-test which is much more powerful than the weak fermat-pseudoprime-test. The test in the question is useful if we $(1)$ can factor $N-1$ and  $(2)$ $N$ is a very-probable prime.

Comment: @Peter What makes this test better in that case? Is it faster, or are you more likely to hit a deciding base?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Usually, a suitable base is found fast then, but of course, there is no guarantee for this.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I do not know which is the best known deterministic primality test, but at least we know that deciding whether a number is prime is in P.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82348/discussion-between-peter-and-tobias-kildetoft).

Answer (score 0):

For Carmichael numbers there is no base $B$ such that condition [b] is fulfilled. Therefore a valid Pratt certificate cannot be created.

Choosing random bases is pretty useless for this test as condition [b] is not fulfilled for each pair of prime and base but only for at least one.

Example: $43$ is prime, but $11^{42/3} = 11^{14} \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$.